# Loop through findbyid mongo

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

```
app.get("/cart", isLoggedIn, async function(req, res){
    var cartsretrieved = [];
    for(var i = 0; i < req.user.cart.length; i++){
        Product.findById(req.user.cart[i]._id, function(err, product){
            if(err){
                req.flash("error", "An Error has occured, Please try again later.");
                return res.redirect("/");
            }
            else if(i == req.user.cart.length - 1){
                return res.render("cart", {product: cartsretrieved});
            }
            cartsretrieved.push(product);
        });
    }
});
```

I am trying to make it easier on the db instead of storing every element with all it's objects i stored the id only and when i need the objects i store it to an array and render it but the code down isn't working so how can i make it
thanks for reading

Comment: Main issue is [JavaScript closure inside loops – simple practical example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/750486/javascript-closure-inside-loops-simple-practical-example) but this won't work reliably anyway because you can't assume that the callbacks are executed in order.

Comment: so what can i do to make it work in this case

Comment: Why do you fetch the documents one by one? Would be much easier to get all of them at the same time and you wouldn't need all that manual work.

Comment: because they are stored as ids in the db not the whole object so how will i fetch them one time

Comment: `Product.find({ id: { $in: req.user.cart.map(cart => cart._id) } })`